# using google firebase storage without authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to share some json file to all user without server and I use google firebase storage service (without user authentication).
Code:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxxx.appspot.com/xxx-main.json");
Task<byte[]> task = storageRef.getBytes(1000000);
while (!task.isComplete())
    StaticTools.sleep(100);

byte[] b=task.getResult();
```

but it raise an exception:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.
```

Storage Rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/XXXXXX.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the new Firebase Storage Console at https://console.firebase.google.com. Navigate through your folders and select your uploaded file. Under the File location tab, there is this field called **Download URL**. Click on it to copy and you will be able to hotlink to this file in your website.

As long as there is no permission settings written in the rules tab, you should be able to use these files publicly.

Comment: downloadable url does not follow security rules. they are available at anyone with the url

Answer (score 3):

Xavier's answer with Download URLs will work.

Your rules should allow public read, but it can take up to 5 minutes for your rules to update across the system.

Comment: how long download urls are valid ?

Comment: they are valid until revoked which can happen through an object update or explicitly through revoking an url in the firebase web console.

Comment: rules dont apply to downloadble urls

Answer (score 3):

I Use this for the latest firebase it worked

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I just delete in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Google firebase storage only works with authenticated user. You can setup anonymous authentification if your app didn't require user authentification.